# Error handling of AVAudioPlayer's contentsOfURL:error: in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer

I followed a tutorial re: [how to create an MP3 Player in Swift](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-mp3-player-with-av-foundation--cms-24482) and I encountered a spot where the syntax has changed between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0.

I've encountered an issue with error handling for the following method:

```
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
```

I'm aware I need to use `try` and `catch` to "Swift2-ify" it. I've done an "apples to oranges" translation of the Swift 1.2 code, but I'm having difficulty making it "apples to apples".

Here are the relevant methods/declarations from the tutorial in **Swift 1.2**.

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func queueTrack(){
    if (player != nil) {
        player = nil
    }

    var error:NSError?
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(tracks[currentTrackIndex] as String)
    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)

    if let hasError = error {
        //TODO: SHOW ALERT HERE
    } else {
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

Here is what I attempted in **Swift 2.0**. It runs, but I get warnings.

```
func queueTrack() {
    if (player != nil) {
        player =  nil
    }

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(tracks[currentTrackIndex] as String)
    // I get a warning to make 'var error' to 'let error' here
    // If I do what the compiler says, I get a warning the error isn't
    // initialized after 'catch' outside the curly braces
    var error: NSError? // TODO: figure out how to remove this warning


    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error)")
        // SHOW ALERT OR SOMETHING
    }

    // Immutable value 'hasError' was never used; consider replacing
    // with '_' or removing it
    // If earlier declaration of error is changed to let, the warning turns
    // into an compiler error

    if let hasError = error {
        // show alert
    } else {
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

What mistake have I made in my translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `var error: NSError?` anymore *at all*, delete it and the related lines.

Now you handle the possible error in the `catch` block.

```
func queueTrack() {

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(tracks[currentTrackIndex] as String)

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error)")
        // SHOW ALERT OR SOMETHING
    }

}
```

Note that this `error` variable in the `catch` block is *not* the same variable as before, it's a new one (of type `ErrorType`) generated by the `catch` block.

There's another syntax for the `catch` block:

```
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error.debugDescription)")
        // SHOW ALERT OR SOMETHING
    }
```

Here the `error` will not be `ErrorType` but `NSError` as usual.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for getting me squared away so quickly and succinctly. I greatly appreciate your help on this.